# ColdFusion Calendar - How can I find day from days in month?

Tags: date, coldfusion, calendar

Here's my code. I got it from a tutorial online.

```
<CFPARAM NAME = "month" DEFAULT = "#DatePart('m', Now())#" />
<CFPARAM NAME = "year" DEFAULT = "#DatePart('yyyy', Now())#" />
<CFPARAM NAME = "currentday" DEFAULT = "#DatePart('d', Now())#" />
<CFPARAM NAME = "startmonth" DEFAULT = "#DatePart('m', Now())#" />
<CFPARAM NAME = "startyear" DEFAULT = "#DatePart('yyyy', Now())#" />
<cfset ThisMonthYear = CreateDate(year, month, '1') />
<cfset Days = DaysInMonth(ThisMonthYear) />
<cfset LastMonthYear = DateAdd('m', -1, ThisMonthYear) />
<cfset LastMonth = DatePart('m', LastMonthYear) />
<cfset LastYear = DatePart('yyyy', LastMonthYear) />
<cfset NextMonthYear = DateAdd('m', 1, ThisMonthYear) />
<cfset NextMonth = DatePart('m', NextMonthYear) />
<cfset NextYear = DatePart('yyyy', NextMonthYear) />
```

and here is my output code.

```
<a href="calendar_day.cfm?month=#month#&day=#THE_DAY#&year=#year#">
```

I'm using this for a visible calendar, and want to be able to select the day from all days in the month. Is there any way to determine the day of the month when clicking on the day in the monthly calendar view?

Comment: "determine the day of the month"?  What do you mean?

Comment: your output code seems a bit lacking

Comment: Question isn't clear enough to be answered.

Comment: I'm with Dan Short, I just don't get it.

Comment: Sorry about the confusion. I want to send the numerical day of the month in a url to another page, to determine the day I'm selecting on the calendar.

Comment: Then you have the code, DatePart("m", someDate), write it into a link, and then retrieve the URL on the next page and adjust your calendar accordingly. How you set the active day in the calendar, and how you grab that day when a user clicks on it, are completely dependent on the calendar system you're using, which you make no mention of.

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you want to use is `#URL.day#`, to get the day variable passed in the URL, but as everyone is saying your question is really confusing.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out, the question is pretty confusing.

*Is there any way to determine the day of the month when clicking on the day in the monthly calendar view?*

You have total number of days in the month in Days var.  On the calendar render, you are likely looping through and displaying each day of the month using that var.  You can easily embed that loop index into your resulting HTML to know what day any given link would refer to.

```
<!--- loop thru all days in current month --->
<cfloop from=1 to=Days index="this_day">
   <!--- display day in the calendar --->
   <a href="calendar_day.cfm?month=#month#&day=#this_day#&year=#year#">Day #this_day#</a>
   <cfif this_day eq CurrentDay>
        <!--- day being displayed is the current day, highlight it or whatever --->
   </cfif>
</cfloop>
```